# unable to boot with GRUB after installing arch-linux

Tags: arch-linux, lvm, grub

i finished to install the Arch linuks with lvm on Luks and rebooted after configuring the GRUB.

when i boot to the USB GRUB i get: [image]

i have edited this page and fixed the UUID number to the sda1

Edit:
i boot with the archiso and when im trying re re-generate :

```
# grub-mkconfig -o /mnt/boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

i get lots of warning all the same:

warning: failed to connect to lvmetad. falling back to internal scaninng .
/run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed no such file or directory.

any ideas?

Comment: You need to show us your grub,cfg

Answer (score 1):

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dm-crypt/Encrypting_an_entire_system#Configuring_the_boot_loader

Please read the Arch wiki section above.

Firstly, you will need to add the `encrypt` and `lvm2` hook into mkinitcpio.conf, and then run:

```
mkinitcpio -p linux
```

Secondly, we need to let grub decrypt the disk in advance of the boot process.

Below I quoted the detail in the Arch wiki:

> In order to unlock the encrypted root partition at boot, the following kernel parameters need to be set by the bootloader:

```
cryptdevice=UUID=device-UUID:lvm root=/dev/mapper/MyVol-root
The <device-UUID> refers to the UUID of /dev/sdaX
```

This is how it works: you will need to decrypt the disk first in kernel parameter so that you can boot.